# Installing Visual C++ Redistributable and licenses

Tags: license, visual-c++, redistributable

I have some software that needs Visual C++ Redistributable. Do I need to acquire some sort of license from Microsoft to install it? I see it's free to download but will it count on the licenses we need to pay if auditors from Microsoft comes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime is free.

Download what version you need from here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

FYI, most programs will install the required version at the same time you are installing the software.

Answer (score 0):

While the Visual C++ Redistributable is free to use, it does come with a license agreement: [License Terms | Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime 2015-2022 - Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/vs2022-cruntime/) -- which the installer asks you to accept upon installation.

In particualar (as of this writing), it prohibits the use in unlawful applications and requires compliance with "domestic and international" export restrictions.

More importantly, **since VC++ 2019, the use of Merge Modules to bundle MSVC++ into your installer package is deprecated, and since VC++ 2022, outright prohibited by the license!** According to [Redistributing Components By Using Merge Modules | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/redistributing-components-by-using-merge-modules?view=msvc-170), MS deemed them more trouble that they're worth and now choose to manage the installed VC++ runtimes themselves via Windows Update.